# In a django site I want to let users create other users that are tied to their accounts

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to let a logged-in and registered user create extra user accounts that he will be the admin of.  These accounts will be special "subordinate" accounts that are tied to the user creating them.  He should be able to add/modify/delete these accounts kind of like the theory of how a Google apps administrator manages the accounts for his company (you are a regular user, but also create/destroy other users.)

The subordinate accounts cannot create/modify/delete accounts (except change their own password and normal user behavior.)  I'm using the django auth model for all of these accounts.  What is a good way to access the auth methods to add/modify/delete accounts from my own custom built webpages without using any admin code?

Answer (score 5):

First, you'll need to [extend your User model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). Then: Add a field that represents the class of user - "subordinate" or "admin". Add a field that references the "admin" User via foreign key so you can group users by their "admin". Create views that check the class of user and allow creation, edit, deletion of "subordinate" user accounts if user class is "admin".